# Msys2: Undefined reference to SSL when compiling in 32bit

Tags: openssl, g++, mingw, mingw32, msys2

I'm trying to compile a 32bit dll in msys2 but I'm having trouble with openssl.

I am currently compiling with this command

```
g++ -std=c++17 --shared -lWs2_32 -lssl -lcrypto main.cpp -m32 -o main.dll
```

which then gives me errors such as

```
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZZN7httplib9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEENKUlP6ssl_stE_clES8_[__ZZN7httplib9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEENKUlP6ssl_stE_clES8_]+0x1fe): undefined reference to `X509_free'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZZN7httplib9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEENKUlP6ssl_stE_clES8_[__ZZN7httplib9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEENKUlP6ssl_stE_clES8_]+0x210): undefined reference to `X509_free'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZZN7httplib9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEENKUlP6ssl_stE0_clES8_[__ZZN7httplib9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEENKUlP6ssl_stE0_clES8_]+0x33): undefined reference to `SSL_ctrl'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st[__ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st]+0x3a): undefined reference to `X509_get_ext_d2i'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st[__ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st]+0xab): undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_get0_data'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st[__ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st]+0xbc): undefined reference to `ASN1_STRING_length'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st[__ZNK7httplib9SSLClient33verify_host_with_subject_alt_nameEP7x509_st]+0x15f): undefined reference to `GENERAL_NAMES_free'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7httplib9SSLClient28verify_host_with_common_nameEP7x509_st[__ZNK7httplib9SSLClient28verify_host_with_common_nameEP7x509_st]+0x16): undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK7httplib9SSLClient28verify_host_with_common_nameEP7x509_st[__ZNK7httplib9SSLClient28verify_host_with_common_nameEP7x509_st]+0x44): undefined reference to `X509_NAME_get_text_by_NID'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i[__ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i]+0x72): undefined reference to `_imp__getaddrinfo@16'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i[__ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i]+0xd4): undefined reference to `_imp__WSASocketW@24'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i[__ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i]+0x104): undefined reference to `_imp__socket@12'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i[__ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i]+0x147): undefined reference to `_imp__setsockopt@20'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i[__ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i]+0x188): undefined reference to `_imp__setsockopt@20'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i[__ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i]+0x1b6): undefined reference to `_imp__freeaddrinfo@4'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i[__ZN7httplib6detail13create_socketIZNS0_20create_client_socketEPKcillRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEUljR8addrinfoE_EEjS3_iT_i]+0x1e7): undefined reference to `_imp__freeaddrinfo@4'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x55): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x90): undefined reference to `BIO_new_socket'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0xac): undefined reference to `SSL_set_bio'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0xd1): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0xef): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x2a9): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIPFiP6ssl_stEZNS_9SSLServer24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_E_ZNS6_24process_and_close_socketEjEUlS3_RNS_6StreamEbRbE0_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x2c7): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x55): undefined reference to `SSL_new'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x90): undefined reference to `BIO_new_socket'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0xac): undefined reference to `SSL_set_bio'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0xd1): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0xef): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x2b4): undefined reference to `SSL_shutdown'
C:/Users/Mateus/AppData/Local/Programs/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Mateus\AppData\Local\Programs\msys64\tmp\ccjeTZvX.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_[__ZN7httplib6detail28process_and_close_socket_sslIZNS_9SSLClient24process_and_close_socketEjjSt8functionIFbRNS_6StreamEbRbEEEUlP6ssl_stE_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_E0_ZNS2_24process_and_close_socketEjjS8_EUlSA_S5_bS6_E1_EEbbjjllllP10ssl_ctx_stRSt5mutexT_T0_T1_]+0x2d2): undefined reference to `SSL_free'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The order of libraries is important, and they should be after the object/source files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the libraries after the source or object that calls them:

```
g++ -std=c++17 --shared main.cpp -m32 -o main.dll -lWs2_32 -lssl -lcrypto
```